# Hive query execution issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

When executing a hive query, here is the output, wondering for "Map 1" and "Reducer 2", what does the 1 and 2 mean?

```
Map 1: 21/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 22/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 23/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 24/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 26/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 27/27    Reducer 2: 0/1
Map 1: 27/27    Reducer 2: 1/1
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: they are the number of mappers and reducers for a task. Map 1 is the first map task.reducer 2 is the second reducer task.

Comment: also as you can see the reducer hasn't started its processing until all the map tasks have finished.

Comment: @vkp, thanks for the answer. So it means the first mapper is running, and the 2nd reducer is waiting, and it does not mean there are only 1 mapped and 2 reducer are used?

Comment: the default number of reducers is set in the configuration file. You can change it if needed. I assume the default reducers are 2 in your case.

Comment: @vkp, how to check default configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hive query is interpreted by the MapReduce framework as a Map-Reduce task. The task gets assigned mappers and reducers based on the input. When the task is in progress you can see the output displayed in terms of  mappers and reducers progress.

Comment: they denote the individual splits in the input data. Each map task processes a input split assigned to it.

Comment: then there should be 27 mappers other than 1?